# iptable localhost connections reported to be blocked, but work ok

Tags: iptables, localhost, fwbuilder

I am using fwbuilder and have tried setting up rules that both allow `lo` interface and source ip `127.0.0.1`, as follows:

```
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i lo   -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -o lo   -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT

...

$IPTABLES -A INPUT  -s 127.0.0.1   -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT  -s 127.0.0.1   -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT
```

The connection appears to work fine, but then why do I see several of these errors in `/var/log/syslog` ??

`RULE 4 -- DENY IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43254 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47654 DPT=4949 WINDOW=256 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0`

**UPDATE**: [output of `iptables -L -v`](http://pastebin.com/mw0dFQ1h)

Comment: It might be worth using `tcpdump` to capture an entire connection with that blocked packet at the end of it.  The way it got to a state where the firewall would block that packet might be enlightening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show all your rules?
For solve your problem, just make rules:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I've updated my question and added a link to the iptables rules

Comment: I was hoping for a more fine-grained method of allowing (stateful) access on the `lo` interface. However, this seems like the easiest way to avoid those false alarms. In case anybody's interested - in fwbuilder you can mark a rule as a `stateless rule` (in rule options). And it would produce a similar iptables rules as @sub specified.

Answer (score 0):

You are only allowing `-m state --state NEW`. Assuming you also have a `RELATED, ESTABLISHED` rule somewhere, you will see a few packet denies like above, with `ACK PSH FIN` or some other non-new flags that the kernel state tracker doesn't recognize as a part of an established or related connection. Usually this happens shortly after you restart iptables and thus reload the connection tracking modules.

Comment: yes, I do have a rule allowing all `RELATED, ESTABLISHED` states. I'm seeing this in the log every 5 minutes or so, which is how frequently munin runs locally (and successfully connects). Any idea how to get rid of this error / allow these `ACK PSH FIN`s ??

Answer (score 0):

You deny INVALID and UNTRACKED packets on your loopback interface.
This can cause icmp packtes amongst others get dropped.

Check out
http://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html#STATEMACHINE and man iptables

Comment: if I'm reading the log correctly, iptables dropped a `TCP` packet, not `ICMP` here.